Implementation of a tag <link rel="preload" as="image" href="image.png"> in header of JoomGallery
I would like to implement preload link into the head of the JoomGallery like
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="image_name.png"> 

Unfortunatlle the following code does not work:
<link rel="preload" as="image" href="<?php echo $this->image->img_src; ?>">

I assume the reason for it is not intialiasated object within head.
How can I fix it?

Try adding the Tag like that:
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
$document = Factory::getDocument();
$document->addCustomTag('<link rel="preload" as="image" href="' . $this->image->img_src . '">');

You can place the addCustomTag call anywhere, where $this->image->img_src actually resolves to a full image path.
